# Deploy Landscape Gui via JUJU Gui on Ubuntu 16.04Lts Server

Tags: juju

virtual lab:

- 1VM for MAAS + JUJU (both installed via ppa stable) on Ubuntu 16.04Lts
- 1VM for JUJU GUI with Ubuntu 16.04Lts
- 1VM for LANDSCAPE with Ubuntu 16.04Lts

I've a problem, I'm trying to deploy Landscape on a node on MAAS but I don't find any like Landscape Dense-Maas bundle for Xenial. Trying to deploy one by one the services, while I've added postgresql the result has been that

[image]

using the following command

```
$ juju debug-log --include unit-postgresql-0 --replay
```

the error is reported here:

[image]

I've tried to remove the service but postgresql rest there, the only way has been to remove the machine.

[image]

How can I deploy Landscape on a node deployed with Ubuntu 16.04? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

postgresql charm is in error state. You've to resolve the issue first to remove it gracefully or kill the machine to forcefully remove the charm.

If you've CLI access, check logs to debug the error:

> $ juju debug-log --include unit-postgresql-0 --replay

To retry once the issue is resolved, run (or **Retry** from Juju GUI)

```
$ juju resolved postgresql/0
```

To retry (bypassing the error), run (or **Resolve** from Juju GUI)

```
$ juju resolved postgresql/0 --no-retry
```

To forcefully remove machine

```
$ juju remove-machine <postgresql-machine/container-number> --force
```

You can remove the machine from Juju GUI by selecting the ' machine' at top right beside 'applications' and then selecting 'destroy' under 'sandbox' section

Comment: thanks Jubaid for your support, but I've rebuild all environment, when it'll be finished I'll try your suggest.

Comment: I've tried to deploy postgrey on a none alone but nothing, I've updated the post with the screen of that error.

Comment: First thing I would suggest you to debug the error, grab the details and look for the main issue. Have you tried resolving the charm (using the Resolve button on left side of the screen) if you just want to remove the charm without debugging the errors?

Comment: I've already done it, and I don't understand how to resolve that error. I've try that also using Ubuntu 14.04 but this time the error is on haproxy, here is the post http://askubuntu.com/questions/881208/deploy-landscape-gui-via-juju-gui-on-ubuntu-14-04lts-server