# Deploy Landscape Dense-Maas Bumble via JUJU Gui on Ubuntu 14.04Lts Server

Tags: juju

virtual lab:

- 1VM for MAAS + JUJU (both installed via ppa stable) on Ubuntu 16.04Lts
- 1VM for JUJU GUI with Ubuntu 16.04Lts
- 4VM for LANDSCAPE with Ubuntu 14.04Lts

MAAS:

[image]
[image]

I've a problem, I'm trying to deploy Landscape Dense-Maas bundle. during the procedure I've obtained that error.

[image]
[image]

using the command:

```
$: juju debug-log --include unit-haproxy-0 --replay
```

[image]

[image]

any suggest?

Comment: Can you try using the latest charms? In landscape dense maas bundle, just remove the revision associated with haproxy and postgresql charm and redeploy the bundle.

Comment: for example, in the bundle change this 'cs:trusty/haproxy-16' to 'cs:trusty/haproxy' and same for postgresql

Comment: I can't to change it on Juju Gui. Where do I have to make that?